# I cannot make php to replace a <p> text by my $_SESSION['userlogged'] value

Tags: php, html, variables, session

I have tried

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

.
.
.

```
<p><?php $_SESSION['loggeduser']; ?>;</p>
```

I have also tried this JS after the

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let vuser = '<%= session.getAttribute("loggeduser") %>';
        document.getElementById("userid").value= "Not set";
    </script>
```

If someone can tell me what am I doing wrong please!
This is my full body code:

```
        <body>
        <section id="MyHeader" style="border:solid red thin;">
        <div id="TheHead" style="width:80%; display:inline-block;">
        <div id="HeadImg" style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
            <a href="main.html">
                <img src="../images/icon-redcross.png" alt="AGR">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="HeadLegend">
            <div id="AGRbrand"><h1>AGR</h1></div>
            <div id="quote">
                <span style="font-size: small;"><i>Properties catalogue</i></span>
            </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="user" style="display:inline-block; width:12%; height:25px;">
        <p id="userid" style="width:100%;"><?php $_SESSION['loggeduser'];?></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let vuser = '<%= session.getAttribute("loggeduser") %>';
            document.getElementById("userid").value= "Not set";
        </script>
        </div>                          
        <div style="width:100%; display:block;">
        <div id="MenuButtons" style="width:80%; display:flex; justify-content:right;">
            <div id="newbtn" class="TopButton"><a href="New.html">New</a></div>
            <div id="exitbtn" class="TopButton"><a href="../index.html">Exit</a></div>
        </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="Subtitle">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: left; width:100%;">
            <h4>Properties</h4>
        </div>
        </div>  
        </section>  
        <div id="Estates" class="pagebreak"></div>
        <section id="MyPage">
        <div id="Home"></div>     
        <div class="page" style="width:100%; background-color: white; ">
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center; width:100%;">
                <div class="ServiceBox">
                    <div class="div-img"> 
                    <img src="../../images/house-B.png" alt="AGR"> 
                </div>  
                <div class="div-info">
                </div>  
                <div class="div-desc">
                </div>  
                <div class="div-btns">
                    <a class="SideButton" href="Edit.html">Edit</a>
                    <a class="SideButton" href="Delete.html">Delete</a>
                    <a class="SideButton" href="pdf-file.html">Pdf</a>                      
               </div>                   
            </div>      
        </div>      
        </div>
        </section> 
        </body>
```

Notes: $_SESSION["loggeduser"] is populated before this page,at the login page; I verified the variable was properly set by a log file I have, and I was able to see the value printed in the log, after the user logs in and before this page is loaded.

Comment: You need to `echo` the value, ie `<?php echo $_SESSION['loggeduser']; ?>` or the short form `<?= $_SESSION['loggeduser'] ?>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did the recommended changes  but they did not work.

Comment: I found what I believe it was the problem, before I was using .html files, I replaced them with .php files and all the php code started to work. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the php version or the goDaddy servers, but in my case the problem was, I was using html extension for the files, I changed them to .php extension and the php code started to work.